# Suggestions needed on PHP Pattern Library - calling methods and structuring components

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I am fairly new to OO PHP and tried to make my own small Pattern Library. I need some feedback on how to structure components. I am currently using echo() to generate the HTML structure. Is there any other way of doing it? Also, is it a good/acceptable practice to create dependencies in the Pattern Library, such as component A calls component B's method.

For example my Button component:

```
<?php

class Button {

    public function __construct($type, $value, $location)
    {
        echo '<input type="button" class="'.$type.'" value="'.$value.'" onclick="location.href='. $location . '" />';
    }
    static function generate($type, $value, $location)
    {
        echo '<input type="button" class="'.$type.'" value="'.$value.'" onclick="location.href='. $location . '" />';
    }

}
```

Is called within Jumbotron:

```
<?php
class Jumbotron {

    public function __construct($header, $paragraph) {
        echo '<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo"><p>I am</p><h1>'.$header.'</h1><p>'.$paragraph.'</p>';
        Button::generate("primary","Latest Projects","'projects.php'");
        echo'</div>';
    }

}
```

Last question: I couldn't call the __construct() method in the Jumbotron and I had to duplicate it and rename it. Is this a proper way of doing it or am I just reinventing the wheel?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Yes I'll do that thank you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is right, and its totally depends on how you wanna initialize your button, injection and design patterns, i would recomend you to see different design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way without **static calling**

```
class Button {
    private $type;
    private $value;
    private $location;
    public function __construct($type, $value, $location)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->value = $type;
        $this->location = $type;

        //echo '<input type="button" class="'.$type.'" value="'.$value.'" onclick="location.href='. $location . '" />';
    }
    public function generate()
    {
        echo '<input type="button" class="'.$this->type.'" value="'.$this->value.'" onclick="location.href='. $this->location . '" />';
    }
}
$button1 = new Button("primary","Latest Projects","'projects.php'");
$button1->generate();

$button2 = new Button("primary2","Latest Projects2","'projects.php'");
$button2->generate();
```

**Here static way**

```
class Button {
    static function generate($type,$value,$location)
    {
        echo '<input type="button" class="'.$type.'" value="'.$value.'" onclick="location.href='. $location . '" />';
    }
}
Button::generate("button","aaaa","location");
Button::generate("button2","aaaa2","location2");
```

Please see different design patterns factory, facade, singleton etc. Go through the design patterns tutorials.
[Link 1: Common Design patterns](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/)
[PHP Design Patterns- Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_design_patterns.htm)